# Sum of field from 5 table on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have 5 tables on MySQL, following:

```
Table A
ID-A  | NAME
A1    | Name A
A2    | Name b

Table B
ID-B | ID-A
B1   | A1
B2   | A2

Table C
ID-C | ID-B | Value-C
C1   | B1   |   1
C2   | B2   |   1
C3   | B1   |   1

Table D
ID-D | ID-A  | Value-D
D1   | A1    | 1000
D2   | A1    | 500
D3   | A1    | 1000
D4   | A2    | 1000
D5   | A2    | 500

Table E
ID-E | ID-A  | Value-E
E1   | A1    | 2000
E2   | A1    | 1500
E3   | A2    | 500
E4   | A2    | 500
E5   | A2    | 1000
```

So, I want sum of value, following:

**1.** `SUM(Value-C)` of Table C AS `tot_C` for each `ID-A` of Table A. 
 **2.** `SUM(Value-D)` of Table D AS `tot_D` for each `ID-A` of Table A. 
 **3.** `SUM(Value-E)` of Table E AS `tot_E` for each `ID-A` of Table A. 
 **4.** `tot_C+tot_D+tot_E` AS `tot_ALL` for each `ID-A` of Table A.

I hope you can help me. 
Thank you, Dear!

Comment: Have you made an attempt that you could show. This will be done using `JOIN`, and there are many example on SO that you could use to form yours.

Comment: Before, I have using JOIN. But, the result is invalid. May you give me a complete code about that? Thank you

Comment: Don't use "-" in table/column identifiers, not even in test/example code

Comment: I can give you 'complete code' when you give me 'complete payment'. SO is here to help you with code that you have tried, not to do the work for you. Show your attempts that give invalid results, and then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tb.id_A id_A, sum(valueC) tot_C 
from fiveTablesSum_C tc 
join fiveTablesSum_B tb on tc.id_B = tb.id_B 
group by id_A;
+------+-------+
| id_A | tot_C |
+------+-------+
| A1   |     2 |
| A2   |     1 |
+------+-------+

select id_A id_A, sum(valueD) tot_D from fiveTablesSum_D group by id_A;
+------+-------+
| id_A | tot_D |
+------+-------+
| A1   |  2500 |
| A2   |  1500 |
+------+-------+

select id_A id_A, sum(valueE) tot_E from fiveTablesSum_E group by id_A;
+------+-------+
| id_A | tot_E |
+------+-------+
| A1   |  3500 |
| A2   |  2000 |
+------+-------+

select
    t1.id_A,
    t2.tot_C, t3.tot_D, t4.tot_E,
    t2.tot_C + t3.tot_D + t4.tot_E tot_ALL
from fiveTablesSum_A t1
left join (
    select tb.id_A id_A, sum(valueC) tot_C
    from fiveTablesSum_C tc
    join fiveTablesSum_B tb on tc.id_B = tb.id_B
    group by id_A
) t2 on t1.id_A = t2.id_A
left join (
    select id_A id_A, sum(valueD) tot_D from fiveTablesSum_D group by id_A
) t3 on t1.id_A = t3.id_A
left join (
    select id_A id_A, sum(valueE) tot_E from fiveTablesSum_E group by id_A
) t4 on t1.id_A = t4.id_A
;
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| id_A | tot_C | tot_D | tot_E | tot_ALL |
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| A1   |     2 |  2500 |  3500 |    6002 |
| A2   |     1 |  1500 |  2000 |    3501 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first query, try like below

```
SELECT 
    SUM(TableC.Value-C) as tot_C,TableC.ID-C
FROM
    TableC
        JOIN
    TableB ON TableB.ID-B = TableC.ID-B
        JOIN
    TableA ON TableA.ID-A = TableB.ID-A;
```

Similarly you can try other other queries as well , You should look for how to use **JOINS**

Comment: I have try like that. For SUM(VALUE-C) is succes. But for SUM about table C and table D is false result

Comment: May you give me a complete code about that? Thank you